# ExtJs 4.2: 'id' of Controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have set the 'id' config of controller like

```
Ext.define('App.controller.popUpController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    /**
     * @cfg {String} view
     * View for which popUpController will act as a controller
     */
    view: [
        'PopUpWindow'
    ],

    id:'testController'
})
```

But when I am trying to retrieve id of controller to pass it to

```
Ext.app.EventBus.unlisten(App.app.getController('popUpController').id)
```

It is returning name of controller: **'popUpController'** not the id: **'testController'**. Although I am achieving my goal to unlisten all event handlers related to my controller but my question is why the **'id'** property is returning me **name** and not the given id of the controller?