# Extjs 4.2: 'hasListeners' property of Ext Component's(panel)

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a panel with around 10 items. For all those items I have implemented "after render" event handler in respective controllers of each item.

This is how I have registered afterrender events in Controller's init method:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#myFirstPanel': {
          afterrender: this.afterrender
        }
    });
}
```

My panel code is like:

```
Ext.define('App.view.popUpWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent();
    },       
    id: 'popup',    
    layout: 'fit',    
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel'
        items: [    
            {
                // One of my custom component
                xtype:'FirstGrid'
            }....//10 items in total                
       ]
    }]
});
```

When I get hasListeners property of my panel's object after my app loads by following code

```
Ext.getCmp('popup').hasListeners
```

It returns me this object

> {afterrender: 10, tabchange: 1}

Now when I destroy my panel by this command

```
Ext.getCmp('popup').destroy()
```

and open my app again(my app is a sub Extjs app of a another Extjs app)

```
Ext.getCmp('popup').hasListeners
```

It returns me this object

> {afterrender: 20, tabchange: 2}

My question is that why even after call to **destroy()**, hasListeners is some how keeping record of old Listeners? I know this object doesn't show the number of listener (I read [api](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-property-hasListeners)) but what is going here then?

Can someone explain this to me? As I have to manually remove old listeners(my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470403/extjs-4-2-id-of-controller) about this), why not .destroy() is automatically destroying all references?

Thank you.